# Does referencing a array outside the closure lead to memory leak?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a set of arrays which i am calling inside my closures, which are declared in another file called utils.

utils.js

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
var array3 = [];
var array4 = [];
```

My Closures.js

```
(function() {

myObject.createWindow= function() {
     someField.value = array1;
})();
```

1. If i am referencing my array1 object which is in some other file to
   another js file which is closures, will it lead to memory leaks.

Comment: You don't "call" arrays. What you're doing there is *referencing* the array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thanks for tip... edited the question... does wrapping the global arrays inside a module pattern make sense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Are you just jealous that you don't know how to "call" arrays and we all do? :)

Comment: I call them "arrays". They usually come.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Array.call([], 5) will create an array of length 5.

Comment: @PO'Conbhui (et. al.): Hah hah hah :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocated memory is garbage collected when there are no ways for it to be accessed anymore. So, if an array is referenced in a closure that can still be called, it won't be garbage collected.

For example:

```
f = function() {
    var arr1 = [];
    var arr2 = [];

    return function() {
        return arr1;
    }
};

v = f();
```

arr2 can be immediately garbage collected, but arr1 can't until the value of v is changed to something else because arr1 can still be accessed.

So, in your case, you have

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

...

f = function() {
    return arr1;
}
```

so arr2 can be garbage collected (assuming it's gone out of scope and isn't referred to anywhere else), but arr1 can't be until there are no more references to it. Specifically, in your case, createWindow refers to array1, so that definitely can't be garbage collected.

But as pointed out in another post, if they both have global scope, then neither will be, because they can still be referred to anywhere.

Comment: but once the function call is finished, should it not get garbage collected.

Comment: One question if v = f() and after that if i make v=null, will that get garbage collected.

Comment: It should do, yes, because you no longer have a way of referencing the array.

Comment: @theJava: In the first example, you can still access arr1 every time you run v(). In the second example, f == arr1, so it's still accessible.

Answer (score 4):

If your array is at the root of your file, it's a global variable.

It will take memory, sure, but there is no specific reason for this memory to grow.

So there is no specific risk of memory leak here.

Comment: If i wrap them inside a module pattern and use it in my all closures, will it make any help or leave it as it is.

Comment: You question in comment isn't really clear. But if you don't copy the array, there is no reason for memory leak. I'd suggest you to use [the profiles tab of your browser's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling) and ask a precise question if you see the memory increasing.

Comment: @theJava: wrapping them in a module pattern is good style, reduces pollution of the global namespace, and will allow garbage collection to be more easily identify objects that are no longer referencable.

Answer (score 2):

Memory is considered to be leaked when it is not released when it should be. Attaching arrays to the global namespace means they will be released when the global namespace is. In other words, for them to leak, it would be because of a browser failure. They will pretty much never be collected until the page loses scope. There is nothing that can affect them after the page loses scope that you can introduce in code.

If you want your arrays to be garbage collected, then put them in a scope which will lose scope at some point. When the scope loses its scope, then the arrays will be *eligible* for garbage collection (but not immediately garbage collected).

Comment: I wonder if you could write a chrome plugin that retains elements from the global namespace across page loads...

Answer (score -2):

It would be profoundly surprising if file->object resolution and garbage collection (the way javascript manages memory in general) were at all related to one another.  It should not cause a memory leak.

Comment: Is there a reason for downvoting this?  It would be difficult to say for sure that this could never cause a memory leak without looking into the various JS interpreters, but the other more liked answer doesn't do so.

Comment: File->object resolution and garbage collection are related. Objects in file scope in a browser are in global scope, so they aren't garbage collected. Objects in file scope in Node.js are in a closure in the file, so they may be garbage collected.